# What would the best way to handle NaN values for both numerical and categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, regression, nan, categorical-data

I am about creating a regression model but I wonder what would be the best way to handle nan values for both numerical and categorical data:

I know that for the numerical columns the next solutions could be useful:

1- Replace it with 0: `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)`

2- Replace it with mean: `df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)`

3- Replace it with median `df.fillna(df.median(), inplace=True)`

4- delete each row, in my target column, has nan value

Is it possible to have overfitting after adopting 2 or 3.
What is the best way to handle both categorical and numeric values in columns

However, I wonder what could be the best choice for categorical data is it after using the one hot encoding ?

Any help could be appreciated !

Comment: It really depends on your dataset. Do you understand why those values could be missing? If you don't know why they are missing, you shouldn't just fill them with some other value, but either remove those rows (bad examples) or columns (bad features). An example to illustrate: I once had missing values for wind speed in my data because they weren't able to measure during a hurricane, I ended up filling those with the _max_ rather than the mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For usual practice, it is preferred to use `df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)` for columns having continuous values and  `df.fillna(df.mode()[0], inplace=True)` for categorical values.

Comment: and If I have mixed columns (continuous and categorical) what should I do?

Comment: We can apply .fillna() column wise so its not an issue at all using `df['column_name'].fillna()`